# environment variables are different when running node app as a subprocess

Tags: node.js, unix, child-process

I created a command-line app that uses a `.env` file in conjunction with the `dotenv` NPM module to handle API credentials.  So invoking the entry point like `node main.js` in the project dir works.

I'm now building a web-interface and invoking this application using the `child_process` module.  The problem is that the environment variables are now mismatched.  The command-line app sees `process.env.APIKey` as `undefined` and it crashes.

Now I think this is a unix-specific issue.  How can I solve this problem (specifically, invoking `main.js` programmatically while retaining its own environment variables scope).

Comment: How are you starting the subprocess? Are you calling `fork`, `spawn`, `exec`, `execFile` or something else? Are you passing the environment explicitly?

Comment: so the application I'm invoking (using execSync) is sitting in its project folder with a .env file with the credentials in it using the dotenv module.  What I wound up doing is setting my "cwd" to this folder with execSync's options parameter.

Comment: How did you set the cwd? Spawning a process with a particular cwd or changing the directory from node.js using `process.chdir` is not necessary. The `config` method inside `dotenv` takes a path to an env file as an argument. https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js#L45

Comment: i didn't use process.chdir (at least not directly).  i did execSync('command', { cwd : '../' }).  in this case i'm calling the process from an application nested one directory deeper.  Calling it while the cwd was './' result in the dotenv setup not working despite the fact that the dotenv config references a .env file in the same dir as the application sits.